# Get Json property which name contains some string

Tags: c#, json, json.net, linq-to-json

I have not typical json that I get when request for profile with userName (in example I show what will be if I query with `username1`. If I query with `username2` then property name is `"field_set_key=\"profile\",username=\"username2\""`

```
"UserProfileResource": {
    "field_set_key=\"profile\",username=\"username1\"": {
      "data": {
        "profile": {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I cannot simply set `JsonProperty` with some name as it is dynamic. So I need to parse it manually somehow.

Yes, it looks simple if I know what profile is requested (what username passed).

Just parsed json string into some `JObject`, build that dynamic property name and get it's value using [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm).

But what can be done in case I don't know username that are requested? Can I get property value, which name contains some string (like `field_set_key=\"profile\"`) using mentioned above LINQ to JSON as example?

Comment: You can use [JsonPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to query json using [SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) As shown in [Querying JSON with SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm). I don't currently have the time to test and write a complete answer but I would start digging in that direction. Just don't miss that left turn in Albuquerque.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, yeah, this is what I did! thx

Comment: Well, if you have a working solution you should probably post it as an answer to your own question. Other people might benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ZoharPeled said in comment, I can use use [JsonPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to query json using [SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) As shown in [Querying JSON with SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm)

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

var userProfile = jObject.SelectToken("UserProfileResource.*.data.profile").ToObject<UserProfile>();
```

In example I parsed my json to `JObject` and from it select profile data using `SelectToken`. As you can see, I also used JSONPath expressions there.

`*` means

> wildcard. All objects/elements regardless their names.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i found this code in a old project hope it will help you out with some things!
(this was used to auto fill address using google maps API)
I posted this as answer because i can't comment because of the 50 reputation:P

```
      //Get all adress components based on street-name & house-number
    public static List<Address> PostalcodeResults(string streetname, string number)
    {
        //Request url
        string url = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + streetname + " " + number + "&result_type=street_address&key=" + API_Key;

        //Webrequest-streamreader
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);

        // json-formatted string from maps api
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        //Create lists for the results from the request
        JObject googleSearch = JObject.Parse(responseFromServer);
        IList<JToken> results = googleSearch["results"].Children().ToList();

        //list to return
        List<Address> list = new List<Address>();

        //foreach result
        foreach (JToken Result in results)
        {
            //Some local variable
            string street = "";
            string house_number = "";
            string zipcode = "";
            string country = "";
            string place = "";
            string provincie = "";
            string Township = "";

            //Foreach adress component from result
            foreach (JToken Adress_Components in Result.First().First())
            {
                //List with types
                IList<JToken> types = Adress_Components["types"].Children().ToList();

                //Foreach type
                foreach (JToken type in types)
                {
                    //determ witch Variable it is
                    if (type.ToString() == "route")
                        street = Adress_Components["long_name"].ToString();
                    else if (type.ToString() == "street_number")
                        house_number = Adress_Components["long_name"].ToString();
                    else if (type.ToString() == "postal_code")
                        zipcode = Adress_Components["long_name"].ToString();
                    else if (type.ToString() == "country")
                        country = Adress_Components["long_name"].ToString();
                    else if (type.ToString() == "locality")
                        place = Adress_Components["long_name"].ToString();
                    else if (type.ToString() == "administrative_area_level_1")
                        provincie = Adress_Components["long_name"].ToString();
                    else if (type.ToString() == "administrative_area_level_2")
                        Township = Adress_Components["long_name"].ToString();

                }
            }
            //MessageBox.Show(" Street: " + street + "\n House nr: " + house_number + "\n Zipcode: " + zipcode + "\n Country: " + country + "\n Place: " + place + "\n Province: " + provincie + "\n Township: " + Township);
            list.Add(new Address(street, house_number, zipcode, country, place, provincie, Township));
        }
        //return the lists
        return list;
    }

    //Get directions from one point to another
    private void getdirections()
    {
        string API_Key = "apikey";
        string url = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=75+9th+Ave+New+York,+NY&destination=MetLife+Stadium+1+MetLife+Stadium+Dr+East+Rutherford,+NJ+07073&key=" + API_Key;

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);

        // json-formatted string from maps api
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //richTextBox1.Text = responseFromServer;
    }
}
```

json response:

```
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Somepostalcode",
           "short_name" : "Somepostalcode",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Somelocality",
           "short_name" : "Somelocality",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Someadministrative_area_level_2",
           "short_name" : "Someadministrative_area_level_2",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "SOmeProvince",
           "short_name" : "SomeShortname",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "SomeCountry",
           "short_name" : "SomeCountryShortage",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "foratted adress",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : ,
              "lng" : 
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : ,
              "lng" : 
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : ,
           "lng" : 
        },
        "location_type" : "",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : ,
              "lng" : 
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : ,
              "lng" : 
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "",
     "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
  }
```

],
   "status" : "OK"
}